# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: WordCount

Tags: java, debugging, hadoop, word-count

I am currently wanting to create a single instance node of Hadoop. So I am following this [tutorial](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/). I ran the following command in terminal:

```
hduser@ubuntu:/usr/local/hadoop$ bin/hadoop jar WordCount.jar geekyomega.WordCount /user/hduser/gutenberg /user/hduser/gutenberg-output
```

Things were going great until I ran into this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: WordCount
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:153)
```

I am attempting to run this example using the following code, where I got from [here](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/WordCount). Here is my version of the code:

```
package geekyomega;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;

public class WordCount {

 public static class Map extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text word = new Text();

    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String line = value.toString();
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
        while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
            word.set(tokenizer.nextToken());
            context.write(word, one);
        }
    }
 } 

 public static class Reduce extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) 
      throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        int sum = 0;
        for (IntWritable val : values) {
            sum += val.get();
        }
        context.write(key, new IntWritable(sum));
    }
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();

    Job job = new Job(conf, "WordCount");

    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    job.setMapperClass(Map.class);
    job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

    job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
    job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

    job.waitForCompletion(true);
 }

}
```

I thought my issue was job instantiation. So I did as follows, I changed:

```
Job job = new Job(conf, "wordcount");
```

To the following, capitalized version:

```
Job job = new Job(conf, "WordCount");
```

But that hasn't helped. Anyone know what could help me here?

Thanks, 
Geeky

PS - I don't want to run the tutorial version of wordcount. What I did was created the project in eclipse, added the hadoop jar to it, and exported it as a jar file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Along with adding the package add the following line as well in the job config part of your program :

**job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);**

Comment: This worked. Can you please explain to me why this was necessary? I copied the code from the tutorial, but I am a bit frustrated that the sample code wouldn't work out of the box after I tweeked it a bit. So to rephrase, why was this missing and why do I need it?

Comment: It is to identify the jar containing the given class. And **why was it missing** can be answered best by the author himself. I always do this, and you should too.

Answer (score 9):

your classname is geekyomega.WordCount

you are not appending the package name . in the command line , just after jar file name, give the fully qualified name of your job class.

Comment: This is true as well and a very good catch. I will give you some rep and amend my question. Thank you!

Comment: @akhilesh this really helped..!!

Comment: Thanks a lot was hitting my head why i am not able to run. Thanks a lot. Upvoted (y)